# Why is my code printing "None" after calling showRectangle()?

Tags: python-3.x

After writing this code for an assignment, I encountered a problem where "None" is printed right after calling showRectangle(). I can't figure out why or how to get rid of it. Can someone explain why?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv53i.png)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhgn4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is:`Rectangle.showRectangle() -> None`.

That means that this method returns nothing (or `None`). So, when you call `print(rect.showRectangle())`, you are calling `showRectangle()`, so it prints the rectangle for you. But at the end, this method returns `None`, therefore `None` is printed.
What you should do is just call `rect.showRectangle()`, instead of `print(rect.showRectangle())`.

Btw:`Area` should be = `self.height * self.width`